# receive text from cmd window after start process using command line

Tags: c#

i am build application who run Wireshark and start sniffing, Wireshark has dumpcap.exe file who receive arguments (interface number, output file etc) and start sniffing and meanwhile i can see in the cmd window the number of packet and this number growing all the time.
my question is how can i catch this number every few seconds in order to show this number on my application windows.

this is my class who start this sniffing:

```
public class DumpPcap
{
    public int _interfaceNumber;
    public string _pcapPath;
    public string _dumPcapPath = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\dumpcap.exe";

    public DumpPcap(int interfaceNumber, string pcapPath)
    {
        _interfaceNumber = interfaceNumber;
        _pcapPath = pcapPath;
    }

    public void startTheCapture()
    {
        List<string> stList = new List<string>();
        ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo(_dumPcapPath);
        process.Arguments = string.Format("-i " + _interfaceNumber + " -s 65535 -w " + _pcapPath);
        process.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.ErrorDialog = false;
        Process dumpcap = Process.Start(process);
        StreamReader reader = dumpcap.StandardOutput;
        //dumpcap.WaitForExit(100000);

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            stList.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

and this is screenshot and i marked in red the field that i want to show in my application:

http://image.torrent-invites.com/images/641Untitled.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to capture output text from the `ProcessStartInfo` how about doing it from the `Process`, and intercept the output data via the `OutputDataReceived` event handler?

Try this replacement to your block of code:

```
List<string> stList = new List<string>();

var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = _dumPcapPath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = 
    string.Format("-i " + _interfaceNumber + " -s 65535 -w " + _pcapPath);
process.Startinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.Startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Startinfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.Startinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Startinfo.ErrorDialog = false;

// capture the data received event here...
process.OutputDataReceived += 
    new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();


private void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs arg)
{
    // arg.Data contains the output data from the process...
}
```

NOTE: I just typed this in without compiling or any serious validating, so be warned, LOL...

Comment: 'System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo' does not contain a definition for 'OutputDataReceived' and no extension method 'OutputDataReceived'

Comment: @DanaYeger: look carefully. I mentioned using`Process`, not `ProcessStartInfo`.

Comment: OK now i can see but still i have crash in process.BeginOutputReadLine(); with error StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.